# Turn Managed bean into EJB

Tags: java, jsf, ejb-3.0, managed-bean

Is it possible to turn a Managed bean into an Enterprise Managed Bean? Would you give some example?

Comment: 'Enterprise Managed Bean' = EJB?

Comment: What would make it "enterprise"? EJB is an overloaded term that encompasses several container-provided services, some of which don't really make sense for a JSF controller.

Comment: It's surely possibe. But would it make sense?

Comment: The sensibility perhaps depends on if we're talking about javax.annotation.ManagedBean or javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean [edit: Oops, just noticed the "jsf" tag].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For turning a POJO bean class into an EJB, add the `@Stateless` of `@Stateful` annotation and implement the `@Remote` or `@Local` (or both) interfaces.  Of course some additional configuration steps will be necessary, but that depends on the particular application server you're using.

Do something along these lines:

```
@Local
public interface ServiceLocal {
}

@Remote
public interface ServiceRemote {
}

@Stateless
public class ServiceEJB implements ServiceLocal, ServiceRemote {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid scenario where you want to use an EJB as your backing bean, then yes you can do it.  JBoss Seam would help you in this.  Check out [this](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/1.2.1.GA/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) for more information.